Randomizing Stacked Rows of Cubes in Geometry Nodes with Fixed Start and End Constraints
I have created a geometry node setup that places cubes along the X-axis with random positions and sizes using the accumulate field node.
I need to place these cubes to match the total length of a curve. The first cube should be 0.2m from the start of the curve, and the last one should stop 0.4m before the end. I have achieved this part.
My problem is that I want to use the same geometry node setup to stack rows of cubes with different random seeds, while keeping the 0.2m and 0.4m constraints. Right now, I can duplicate the first row, but the cubes are the same in each row. I want each row to be different.
I have attached a screenshot showing my current progress, where each layer is identical. The goal is to have different rows, but each row should have the same start position and the same end position than the others.
Thank you in advance,
Best regards,
Etienne



Instead of instancing the same line 10 times, you should wrap your node tree with repeat zone and repeat all process 10 times:
I removed last instancing from your node tree and grouped it:

Seed value will be changed from line to line, I added 1 to it each iteration:

And finally, Offset the line each step using set position


Oh my god this is exactly what I needed, thank you so much for your time and your help !!
